# cant transfer ether from account to account in a solidity smart contract

Tags: solidity, transactions, remix

```
pragma solidity >=0.4.21 <0.7.0;

contract Insurance {

    address payable public contractOwner;

    struct InsuranceTaker {
        string name;
        string vehicleNo;
        address insuranceTakerAddress;
        bool policyValid;
        uint lastPayment;
    }

    constructor() public {
        //contractOwner will have the address of the account that first deployed the smartContract
        //in our case the appropriate insurance company
        contractOwner = msg.sender;
    }

    mapping(address => InsuranceTaker) public insuranceTakers;

    //can be annual, half-yearly, quaterly or monthly
    uint public policyPeriod = 30;

    function signUp(string memory _name, string memory _vehicleNo) public payable returns(uint) {
        //to check if new insurance taker has enough ether in their account
        require(msg.sender.balance > 10 ether, "Not enough ether!");
        //setting the structure variables
        InsuranceTaker storage customer = insuranceTakers[msg.sender];
        customer.name = _name;
        customer.vehicleNo = _vehicleNo;
        customer.insuranceTakerAddress = msg.sender;
        //first premium to be paid upfront
        //first premium paid to the insurance company
        //require(msg.value == 0.01 ether,"err1");
        contractOwner.transfer(getPremium());
        customer.policyValid = true;
        customer.lastPayment = now;
        return (200);
    }

    //calculates and returns the premium to be paid by the insurance taker
    function getPremium() public payable returns(uint256) {
        //insuranceTaker customer = insuranceTakers[insuranceTaker];
        //premiumAmount = 1 ether;
        return 1 ether;
    }

    //to check if a insurance taker is currently insured
    function isInsured(address insuranceTaker) public view returns(bool) {
        InsuranceTaker storage customer = insuranceTakers[insuranceTaker];
        return (customer.policyValid && (customer.lastPayment + policyPeriod < now));
    }

    //modifier onlyBy(address _account) {
    //    require(msg.sender == _account,"errrr");
    //    _;
    //}
    //calculates the damage amount to be paid to insurance taker in case an accident occours
    //function damageCalculator() public onlyBy(contractOwner) view returns(uint) {
    //    return(1 ether);
    //}

    uint public damageAmount = 2 ether;



    //
    function payPremium(address insuranceTaker) public payable {
        InsuranceTaker storage customer = insuranceTakers[insuranceTaker];
        require(isInsured(insuranceTaker),"err2");
        //premiumAmount = getPremium();
        require(msg.value == getPremium(),"err3");
        contractOwner.transfer(msg.value);
        customer.policyValid = true;
        customer.lastPayment = now;
    }

    //claim function
    function claim() public payable {
        require(isInsured(msg.sender),"sorry signup for the policy first!");
        msg.sender.transfer(damageAmount);
    }
}
```

Comment: Which function are you calling? What parameters are you using? Which compiler and version are you using? How are you running the tests?

Comment: im calling function signUp("ava","1001"), compiler version 0.6.1, not really running any tests but im running this on remix IDE. im deploying the contract from first account and calling the signUp function from another second account. What i need is ether transfer from second to first, which is not happening

Comment: Did you get an error? What are you expecting to happen? It seems to work as it is written, when calling `signUp` the contract will transfer 1 ether to the owner (if the contract has enough balance). The check for `msg.sender.balance > 10 ether` seems irrelevant, perhaps you wanted to wirte `msg.value >= 1 ether` instead.